# Why do we have a specification tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just found out that we have a specification tag. Can we remove it because it doesn't say anything about the problem? Or just give me a reason for that we even have it!

[specification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/specification)

Now when there are **zero** questions with the tag. Can we remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this tag is [used in different ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/specification?sort=active&pagesize=50):

- Technical standards, such as those [of freedesktop.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78321/what-desktop-file-options-are-available).
- [Coding standards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216055/someone-tell-me-why-people-writing-gnu-code-use-like-that) (which are, in a sense, *specifications* of how to write code).
- [Obtaining](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62830/how-to-list-the-simplest-way-of-hardware-specification) technical [specifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-do-i-check-system-specifications) of hardware.
- Questions [about what](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88928/can-this-spec-do-smooth-and-lag-free-flash) Ubuntu [can do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221623/can-i-install-ubuntu-12-10-on-an-acer-aspire-laptop) on hardware, given [particular specifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192878/will-ubuntu-run-smoothly-thx).
- [Requests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88627/recommend-me-a-serious-work-pc-spec) for hardware specifications (i.e., hardware recommendations, which in this context are often shopping recommendations).
- The general, colloquial sense of [specifying something](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106167/how-to-archive-with-ignoring-files-larger-than-100mb) (i.e., stating it, indicating it).

So we have nine questions, and six separate meanings of the tag, some of which relate a little bit to each other, and some of which do not relate at all.

So **yes**, we should get rid of this tag.

But as there are only nine questions, we can just retag them (perhaps once there's a stronger community consensus that this tag should not exist).

Comment: I removed all the tags from the questions that were using it, since it doesn't help the question having a specification tag, hardware-specification maybe, but not just specification. So now can we delete it.

Comment: @Alvar There's typically no need to delete a tag; it will go away after a while assuming nothing new is tagged with it. Thanks for untagging it!